# Trying to use selenium to automate signups. Running into a problem

Tags: python, selenium

Currently trying to automate signups on 'mail.com' using Selenium. So far i've managed to get the program to go to the URL. The problem i'm having is that even when I copied the full XPATH of "Sign Up" i'm getting an:

"`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[114]/td[2]"}`"

error

Here is the code i'm working with so far:

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='pathtochromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.mail.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

# Delay added to allow elements to load on webpage
time.sleep(30)

# Find the signup element
sign_up = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[114]/td[2]')
```

Comment: The xpath for the button "sign up" appears to be different that what you listed. Also, why not just use the id? xpath can be more brittle in certain circumstances. id for the button is signup-button

Comment: Tried:
sign_up = driver.find_element_by_xpath('signup-button')
Still getting same error

Comment: Try this xpath= `.//a[@id='signup-button']/span` with explicit wait

Comment: well, you do have to use find_element_by_id if you are targeting an id. sign_up = driver.find_element_by_id('signup-button')

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionsChains to scroll to ensure the element is in view.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

some_page_item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('some_class')
ActionsChains(driver).move_to_element(some_page_item).click(some_page_item).perform()
```

Also another tip... instead of simply using time.sleep() to wait for an element to appear, instead use WebDriverWait

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait_for_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME ,"some_class_name")))
```

30 is the amount of seconds that it will wait until the item appears; however if it appears before 30 seconds then it will immediately continue execution. If 30 seconds passes and the item doesn't appear a timeout error will occur.